# In Context of Chomskhy classification of formal languages

Tags: elementary-set-theory, formal-languages, context-free-grammar

Is it possible that `an ambiguous context free language also be a liner context free`.
I have doubt regarding `scope of ambiguous language` in below Venn-diagram.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading your observation in the right way, I believe you are right.

It was proved by Ogden (as an application of his famous Pumping Lemma) that $\{ a^ib^jc^k \mid i=j \mbox{ or } j=k \}$ is inherently ambiguous, meaning is has no unambiguous context-free grammar. At the same time the language is linear.

Thus, in the Venn-diagram the sets "Linear CFL" and "(inherently) Ambiguous CFL" should intersect.

Comment: Correct... I learnt about this language in `peter Linz`. Hendrik Jan except this every thing right na?

Comment: Yes, I think that is the only point that should be changed in the figure.